# Fold Expression: parser stackoverflow

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, variadic-templates, c++17

Hi I want to use fold expressions `,` operator but MSVC keeps annoying me with C1026->Program is to complex. I have broken down the problem to minimal example:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
template<size_t idx>
void foo()
{
    //do some stuff
}
template<typename Ts>
struct ApplySomeFun;

template<size_t... Ts >
struct ApplySomeFun<std::index_sequence<Ts...>>
{

    static void execute() 
    {
        (void(foo<Ts>()), ...);// C1026
    }


};

int main()
{   
    ApplySomeFun<std::make_index_sequence<1024>>::execute();
}
```

This works in gcc but not in msvc. So my question is how to build this in msvc and keep the foldexpression clarity.

Comment: Well, `1024` elements in a single parameter pack is a lot. Do you really need a fold expression that long?

Comment: Fold expression is not 100% necessary but it would be cool  because it looks so elegant and compiles fast(at least on gcc).

Comment: Do you understand that it doesn't compile simply because the number it too large? Unless you truly need `1024` for a real-world problem, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I think that HolyBlackCat is true: the problem is that `1024` is too large for this type of solutions. It's easy develop a C++14 alternative, not so elegant but not really different. But if the problem is the `1024`, I suppose that will fail the C++14 solution too.

Comment: Yes the 1024 is needed. I think i will try the c++14 path.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need so many? If the values are sequental, can't you use a `for` loop instead? (Also, you should ping people with @username when replying to them not under their own posts. Otherwise they don't get notifications and might not reply, unless they revisit the page like I did.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  I want reverse digit indexing for an arbitrary array via compile time generated swap operations for my fft projekt(reinventing the wheel out of curiosity).

Comment: Do you have to perform this unrolling at compile-time?  It would be far easier (also easier to read and understand) to make `idx` a regular function argument of `foo` and then do a for-loop at runtime.

Comment: @Caradhras It's even better: You can put `for` loops into `constexpr` functions. Imho it would be a lot more reasonable than using template trickery.

Comment: @HenriMenke no i dont have to but i measured it and compile time is 2~4 times swap faster than standart on O2 gcc.(The reindexing part of the fft)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workarround (thanks max66 for the hint).

```
template<size_t idx>
void foo()
{
    std::cout << idx << std::endl;
}
template<typename Ts>
struct ApplySomeFun;

template<size_t... Ts >
struct ApplySomeFun<std::index_sequence<Ts...>>
{

    static void execute()
    {
        int unused[] = { 0, ((void)foo<Ts>(), 0)... };//Expander trick
        (void)unused; // blocks warnings
    }


};

int main()
{
    ApplySomeFun<std::make_index_sequence<1024>>::execute();
}
```

Not as nice but it works.